# What is wrong with this EC2 UserData powershell script?

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using AWS S3 to launch a new fleet of spot instances and trying to set up a powershell script to run at luanch as per the instructions here(http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-windows-user-data.html#user-data-powershell)

Here's the powershell script which generates a name for the server with a random string and then restarts the computer:

```
<powershell>
$rnd = ([char[]] (65..90) | get-random -count 3) -join ''
$name = "spot-server-$rnd"

Rename-Computer -NewName $name
shutdown /r /f
</powershell>
```

I've added the script to the UserData field when launching the instances, however, when the instance launches it doesn't seem to work.

NOTE: when i run the script using the powershell terminal it works (renames the computer and restarts the machine)

UPDATE/SOLUTION: I believe the issue was that the AMI I used did not have User Data Enabled in the EC2 Service Properties.  I solved the issue by following these steps:

1. Go to EC2 Service Properties, check the User Data checkbox / click on "Shutdown with Sysprep"
2. Create a new AMI from that instance that just got shut down
3. Launch a new instance using the new AMI and specify the User Data script

Comment: As an aside: Here's how you can create the random 3-character sequence more simply and more efficiently: `([char[]] (65..90) | get-random -count 3) -join ''`

Comment: Can you tell if the script is executing at all? Do you know what account is running the script and if it has rights to make the changes? I recommend putting Add-Content -Value 'Debug' -Path C:\Users\Public\Desktop\test.log -Force between $name and Rename-Computer to see if it executes until that point. Look for the log file on the desktop after.

Comment: it wasn't running at all. pls see my updated response above. thanks!